# I messed up the Master Branch and project wont load, how do i make a new master branch?

Tags: github, branch

So our Master branch is f*cked how can I delete that master branch and make a new master from my current working branch?
Thanks!

and I always keep getting this change being made. I literally do nothing and this happens. Is the .vs folder supposed to be on Github?

Also, I keep getting changes in the csproj file and cache. What are those? I'm new to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other branch:

```
# First, drop the messed-up branch:
$ git branch -D master

# Create a new master branch from your current branch:
$ git checkout -b master

# Force push it to GitHub:
$ git checkout master
$ git push --force origin master
```

Comment: @IbraheemGhaffar yup

Comment: I did that it GitBash says there's no master branch?

Comment: @IbraheemGhaffar if you don't have a master branch, just skip the first step - if there's no such branch, there's no need to delete it.